# How to allow specific extensions and file size to wp_mail attachment?

Tags: attachments, forms, wp-mail

I am trying to create a form with an attachment option that will be sent to an email when the form is submitted on a wordpress site.

My codes work fine and it sends email in a HTMKL table format to my email address. Also I am able to send attachment using the codes. The issue arises when I consider the attachment file extensions and file size. I do not know that how to restrict big size of files and set attachments for some allowed extensions only.

My code is:

```
<?php
//Setup an empty array.
$errors = array(); 
    if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "New reservations request";
    $hotel = $_POST["hotel_url"];
    $sender = $_POST["sendername"];
    $senderEmail = $_POST["senderEmail"];

    //Check the name and make sure that it isn't a blank/empty string.
    if(empty($sender)){
        //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
        $errors['sendername'] = "Please enter your name!";
    }

    /*  attachment */   
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"],WP_CONTENT_DIR .'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']));
    $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/".$_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);    

    if(empty($errors)){

        $mailBody = "<table border='1'>
                       <tr>
                        <th>No</td>
                        <th>Item</td>
                        <th>Description</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td>01</td>
                        <td>Hotel</td>
                        <td>$hotel</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td>02</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>$sender</td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                        <td>03</td>
                        <td>E-Mail</td>
                        <td>$senderEmail</td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>";  

            $headers = array('From: '.$_POST['sendername'].' <'.$_POST['senderEmail'].'>');

            $mail_sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $mailBody, $headers, $attachments );   
        }
    }

    if ($mail_sent) {
?>
    <p>Request sent</p>

<?php 
} else {
?>

<form id="" name="" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="hotel_url" value="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" />

    <div class="section-heading"><h6>Your Details</h6></div>    
    <div class="label-input-wrapper">
        <div class="form-label">Name</div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" name="sendername"/>
            <?php if(isset($errors['sendername'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['sendername'].'</span>'; } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="label-input-wrapper">
        <div class="form-label">E-Mail</div>
            <div class="form-input">
                <input type="email" name="senderEmail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required value="<?PHP if(!empty($errors)) { echo $senderEmail;} ?>"/>
            </div>
    </div>  

    <label for='uploaded_file'>Select A File To Upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="attachment">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

The above code send the attachment to my mail and it saves the file into my uploads dirctory.
I know I have to do something around this area **/*  attachment */** to allow specific extensions and size of the file. but how to do that?
eg: if I have to allow .png, .jpg, .pdf only and the maximum file is 1mb how can I do that? where and what code I have to amend into the above codes?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following condition before the file upload functionality -

```
$allowedExts = array("pdf", "jpg", "png");

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
  //your file upload code and other stuffs
} else {
  echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Referred from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

See 'Restrictions on Upload' section.